# Exchange EWS Calendar title rewrite for room mailboxes

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Our IT has provided me with a service account (`ex-sa-devtest@mydomain.de`) that has delegate rights to a room's mailbox (`EX-Room-A@mydomain.de`) and a user's mailbox (`user.a@mydomain.de`).

In Outlook, running as `user.a`, I created an event using `EX-Room-A` as room. Now here is the matrix what happens in Outlook Web Access and by using the EWS API FindItems (resp. GetItem):

- using the credentials of `user.a`, I see the correct event details (Subject and Body) on the mailbox of `user.a`. When accessing the mailbox of `ex-room-a`, I get "ErrorFolderNotFound: The specified folder could not be found in the store."
- Using the credentials of `ex-sa-devtest` on mailbox of `ex-room-a`, I see Subject="User A " (note the space at the end) and Body is empty. On mailbox of `user.a`, I see correct Subject and Body.

What causes the "rewrite" of the Subject field and the emptying of the Body field when the service account accesses the room mailbox?

The SOAP XML I use is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/><ns1:TimeZoneContext><ns1:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/></ns1:TimeZoneContext></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:FindItem>
<ns2:ItemShape><ns1:BaseShape>AllProperties</ns1:BaseShape></ns2:ItemShape>
<ns2:CalendarView StartDate="2017-12-06T00:00:00+01:00" EndDate="2017-12-06T23:59:59+01:00"/>
<ns2:ParentFolderIds>
<ns1:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"><ns1:Mailbox><ns1:EmailAddress>ex-room-a@mydomain.de</ns1:EmailAddress></ns1:Mailbox></ns1:DistinguishedFolderId>
</ns2:ParentFolderIds>
</ns2:FindItem>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reason this information is removed by the Mailbox assistant as part of the Automatic Processing logic. You can configure this using the Set-CalendarProcessing cmdlet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx eg

> The DeleteSubject parameter specifies whether to remove or keep the subject of incoming meeting requests. Valid input for this parameter is $true or $false. The default value is $true.
>   This parameter is used only on resource mailboxes where the AutomateProcessing parameter is set to AutoAccept.

Comment: Hmm. What is the security reason, given that a normal user can't access the detailed event information anyway? And for the cmdlet - the Exchange server is 2013. Can I simply tell our central IT to set the DeleteSubject parameter to false on the target mailboxes and it will work?

Comment: Let say you have a Meeting room call Meeting Room 1 your HR department schedules a meeting with a subject about redundancies. Meetings are between people there subjects and bodies should only be disclosed to those attending. With a meeting room everybody may have read access to see who is scheduling meeting but they don't need to know the subject or the body of the meetings hence why they are removed by default . Setting the Deletesubject and DeleteBody will work that's what they do but you introducing a information disclose risk.

Comment: Thanks for both the explanation and the fix, it worked perfectly!